# how to display likes and dislikes

Tags: php

im trying to make a simple comments like and dislike sytem with php. Here are my comment and like dislike table.

[image: likedisliketable]

[image: comments table]

When the user clicks on like it changes the value from 0 to 1(i didnt make the dislikes for the moment), and im stuck on how to display it correctly. I use rowcount to count where likeRatio is equal to 1 and idComm is equal to the comment id, i cant figure out how to get the comment id on each comment.

Model

```
        public function like(){
            $conn = $this->bdd();
            $insert = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO likedislikecomm (idComm,pseudoUti, likeRatio) VALUES (?,?,?)");
            $insert->execute([$_GET['id'],$_SESSION['utilisateur'],1]);
        }

        public function showLikes(){
            $conn = $this->bdd();
            $tes = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM likedislikecomm WHERE likeRatio=1 AND idComm='what do i need to put here'');
            $likes = $tes->rowCount();
            return $likes;  
        }
```

controller

```
    function PageJeu(){
        $uti = new Utilisateur(); 
        $test = $uti->showComment();
        $reviews = $uti->showReview();
        $likes= $uti->showLikes();
        require('view/pageJeu.php');
    }
```

view

```
<?php foreach($test as $commentsFetch){?>
            <div class="comment">
                <div class="user">
                    <div class="profilePicContainer">
                        <img class="profilePic" src="images/images.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="pseudoDate">
                        <p class="pseudo-reviewer"><?= $commentsFetch['pseudo']; ?></p>
                        <p class="date"><?= $commentsFetch['date']; ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p class="content-comment">
                    <?= $commentsFetch['comment']; ?>
                </p>
                <div class="thumbs">
                    <div class="like">
                        <a style="display:flex;"href="index.php?action=1&id=<?= $commentsFetch['pseudo']; ?>">
                            <p class="likeNum"><?= $likes ?></p>
                            <i style="color:green;" class="fas fa-thumbs-up fa-2x"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dislike">
                        <a style="display:flex;"href="index.php?action=2&id=<?= $commentsFetch['id']; ?>">
                            <p class="dislikeNum">-5</p>
                            <i style="color:red;" class="fas fa-thumbs-down fa-2x"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php }?>
```

rooter

```
        if ($_GET['action'] == "pageJeu"){
            PageJeu();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay Gobii,
Simply pass comment id to "showLikes" method and change :

```
$tes = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM likedislikecomm WHERE likeRatio=1');
```

To :

```
$tes = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM likedislikecomm WHERE likeRatio=1 AND idComm=<comment id>');
```

And dont forget to use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) .

Comment: hello, thx for the answer, of course i tried to do that but how can i fetch the id of each comment ?

Comment: You already have each comment id just pass it : PageJeu($commentsFetch['id'])

Comment: Btw You should call the function inside the foreach loop.

Comment: Sorry i haven't noticed before that PageJeu return both comments and likes, Just write a new method for the likes and call it inside the foreach loop. good luck.